# Unable to access port 8086 publicly

Tags: port, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am running alfresco on port 8086. I now want to give public access to the site. The port 8086 is opened. However, I am not able to access it from outside. What should I do give it public access?

Comment: "The port 8086 is opened" - I'd be willing to bet it's *not.* You need to open it in the entire network path from the outside world to your server, not just *at* your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that your port number is not on running on 127.0.0.1:8086

It should be public_ip:8086

Use this command to check on which ip its running :

netstat -ntlpu

If you are behind a router check your port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Check if port is opened on the router or firewall. Maybe you just need some port forwarding.
Check if you have some program firewall like ufw or shorewall if you're running it under Linux.

Good luck, have fun.